# creating vm from managed data disk

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have OS data in a managed azure data disk. I want to create a VM from this data disk. I tried using 
`az vm create --resource-group myResourceGroup --location eastus --name myVM \ --os-type linux --attach-os-disk myManagedDisk`

The issue that I am facing is that the newly created vm is up and running, however when I try to connect to it via ssh using the IP address, I am unable to do so.

Also how do I give an username and password to this newly created VM? It says the `--admin-username` and `--admin-password` options are unavailable for this type of command?

Comment: What do you mean `unable to ssh the IP address`? timeout or wrong password?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT I dont get any error, nor does it prompt for password. The terminal doesn't show anything.

Comment: Can you restart that Azure VM via Azure portal?

Comment: Yes I am able to start and stop this VM

Comment: Could you tell me the public IP address? Let me test it.

Comment: yeah. The IP address is - 52.168.25.228

Comment: Please check that VM's NSG settings? add port 22 to inbound rules.

Comment: I checked the settings. Its already present

Comment: Do you have another Azure VM in the same Vnet? use that VM to connect it.

Comment: Yes I have another VM present in same vnet. I connected to this second VM and then tried to ssh to the VM which I am trying to actually ssh to. But again, I am not getting any response on the terminal

Comment: Can you ping that VM's private IP address? you can find the private IP address via Azure portal-> Vnet

Comment: Actually ping did not work for any VMs but telnet did. So I used telnet to the VMs private IP but it did not work

Comment: ping works for internal private IP address. Is there NSG associate with subnet? Please check it

Comment: No. The NSG is not associated to any subnet

Comment: Have you change ubuntu firewall settings? maybe firewall will block it. By the way, could you please shutdown your original VM and create a snapshot of that OS disk, then follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-copy-managed-disks-to-same-or-different-subscription) to create new VM.

Comment: Okay will try it. Thanks a lot for you time and assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can't login the new VM with original passwrod, please **Reset Password** via Azure portal, then use new Password to login it.

> It says the --admin-username and --admin-password options are
>   unavailable for this type of command?

Yes, Azure does not support reset username and password for an existing OS disk.

If you want to reset username and password, maybe you should **create a new image** from this VM. Create new image will general this VM, and remove user settings, then you can't login that original VM, if you want create new VM image, backup that os disk first.

**Update**:

Please follow those steps to copy managed disk and create new VM:
1.Stop original VM, then create snapshot of that OS disk via Azure portal.
2.Use the snapshot to create an new disk.
3.Use New OS disk to create Azure VM.

```
#Provide the subscription Id of the subscription where managed disk exists
$sourceSubscriptionId='yourSourceSubscriptionId'

#Provide the name of your resource group where managed disk exists
$sourceResourceGroupName='mySourceResourceGroupName'

#Provide the name of the managed disk
$managedDiskName='myDiskName'

#Set the context to the subscription Id where Managed Disk exists
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $sourceSubscriptionId

#Get the source managed disk
$managedDisk= Get-AzureRMDisk -ResourceGroupName $sourceResourceGroupName -DiskName $managedDiskName

#Provide the subscription Id of the subscription where managed disk will be copied to
#If managed disk is copied to the same subscription then you can skip this step
$targetSubscriptionId='yourTargetSubscriptionId'

#Name of the resource group where snapshot will be copied to
$targetResourceGroupName='myTargetResourceGroupName'

#Set the context to the subscription Id where managed disk will be copied to
#If snapshot is copied to the same subscription then you can skip this step
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $targetSubscriptionId

$diskConfig = New-AzureRmDiskConfig -SourceResourceId $managedDisk.Id -Location $managedDisk.Location -CreateOption Copy 

#Create a new managed disk in the target subscription and resource group
New-AzureRmDisk -Disk $diskConfig -DiskName $managedDiskName -ResourceGroupName $targetResourceGroupName
```